# From a high level, what is the best way to implement a fitness app which reads workouts from a database?

Tags: android, ios, database, mongodb, react-native

I'm designing a fitness app where a trainer would upload workouts to a database and a client could access those workouts via an app. This is easy enough to setup, however, I'm struggling to find a good way to upload workouts to a database in a way that someone who is non technical could easily do. I've been primarily playing around with FirebaseDB, but I'm open to suggestions. I'm trying to avoid having to create my own app for the trainer to input data and upload to the database as it will take extra time. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking to expand your app in near future i suggest you to avoid FirebaseDB. Go with MS-SQL. Create User Table and add a Field may be called as  'Member_Types' (Admin|User). If the logged in user is Admin then Show him Different Page from where He can Upload Data by just inserting in Textboxes/Dropdowns/etc,etc and Clicking One Button Click. Whereas if the user logged in as a USER type show him the page which shows the data uploaded by Admin.
Using FirebaseDB is OK but If you want to deal with really complex data which this app can (In case to want to expand this app and want to add more and more features). I even Suggest if u are going with MS-SQL , Create your Own WebAPI to handle the requests.
All the Very Best for your App.